# How to use my own kernel function for bayesian optimization in Python

Tags: python, optimization, scikit-learn, bayesian, gaussian-process

I am using the Python library [fmfn/BayesianOptimization](https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization) to perform a Bayesian Optimization with Gaussian Process. I have to change the kernel function to one created by me.

```
# My kernel function
k(x,y)=1/theta_1*np.e**(theta_2*d(x,y))**2
```

From what I understand, the library [fmfn/BayesianOptimization](https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization) calls to [sklearn.gaussian_process](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html). My question is, how do I have to implement my kernel to make it compatible with sklearn and how do I pass it on as an argument?

Comment: Your kernel looks just like a (scaled) `sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.RBF` kernel.  I think you should just use that.  If I'm wrong, or you still want to use your own, make a subclass of Kernel https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.Kernel.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.Kernel

Comment: Thanks you for the answear, I am going to expand the information a little more, the kernel function it is not exactly how i put it, 

`k(x,y)=1/theta_1*np.e**(theta_2*d_kendall(randomkey(x),randomkey(y)))**2` 

where d_kendall is the kendall distance between two permutations and randomkey function convert a vector of reals into permutations, I suppose that this kernel is not among the basic ones, so I would have to create it myself, right?

Comment: Yea, in that case, you'll need to create it yourself.  It will probably help you to check out the existing implementations: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/114616d9f6ce9eba7c1aacd3d4a254f868010e25/sklearn/gaussian_process/kernels.py

Comment: There is a guide or tutorial on how to do it?, I feel very confused reading the code of the other kernels, I don't know exactly how to replicate it